# Element not found after new sessions is created

Tags: r, selenium, docker, rselenium

I created a script to fetch some data from a chess site. To do this I used the info found in [this tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html). So I followed the following steps:

- pulled image
- started container

I connected to the server like this:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",
                      port = 4445L)

remDr$open()
```

Logging in I did as follows:

```
remDr$navigate("http://chesstempo.com")
user <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='usernameField']")
```

This worked perfectly. Afterwards I tried to automate it using Windows Task Scheduler (hourly check) and that's when things started to go south. It works just one time and then stops functioning. I got the logs and found out the session is terminated after the first try:

```
22:04:12.588 INFO - Session d40d129f-f15c-4ba2-83a6-9d5b16acf2d1 deleted due to client timeout
22:04:12.681 INFO - Session 60d4e465-e4ff-4b97-8dab-c947313c1191 deleted due to client timeout
22:04:12.760 INFO - Session b4576ba5-f2b3-4c6b-bdd6-82dc4b06f1af deleted due to client timeout
```

After the session is terminated the next time these are the logs I get:

```
08:45:01.770 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]])
08:45:01.772 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
08:45:02.983 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]]
08:45:03.004 INFO - Executing: [get: http://chesstempo.com])
08:46:23.141 INFO - Done: [get: http://chesstempo.com]
08:46:23.151 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.xpath: //input[@id='usernameField']])
08:46:23.594 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='usernameField']"}
```

I don't have a lot of experience in using either Selenium or Docker so I'm at a loss how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance for any help and please let me know if I forgot to add some crucial information. I had quite a lot of data in the logs but dumping everything seemed like overkill.